# Always running service

Tags: java, android, service, push-notification, android-service

I'm working on an Android Application (java) for my school with an E-Mail client in it, and I want to create a Service which is always running in Background and refreshes the Inbox every hour, and if there's a new message, the Service should create a push notification which sends the user to an Activity containing the inbox of the email.

How can I create such a Service which is not killed when the Application exits?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two keys:

1. You should start the service with the `startService` call rather than binding.
2. In the service the `onStartCommand` should return `START_STICKY`.

A lot of useful information is on the android pages, why not start with http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html.

Answer (score 0):

Take a gander at the [Android API Guides](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/index.html), specifically the one on [Processes and Threads](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/processes-and-threads.html). That should answer your question!